# Eclipse not showing SVN outgoing_flag > on Package explorer

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I have `>` defined as the outgoing flag in Subversive in Eclipse Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0):

[image: Label Decorations]
[image: Text Decorations]

Despite that however, I do not see `>` decoration at the package or project levels despite having changes (see red circles in image below, on places where I have a file change in green circle).

[image]

It is also not shown in the Project Explorer view:
[image: Project Explorer View]

Does anyone now what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

check general preferences if 'svn' is checked or not

[image: snapshot]